# PHP Laminas Framework Flash Messenger replaces space with " + "

Tags: php, zend-framework3, laminas, flashmessenger

[image: message when creating]

The flash messenger replaces the message spaces with the " + " symbol when trying to create something, but it works perfectly when updating.

[image: message when updating]

How to remove the " + " symbol?

code for creating

```
            // success
            $text = $this->translate('The group %s has been created successfully.');
            $message['success'] = sprintf($text, $group['name']);
            $cookie = new SetCookie('newGroup', $group['name'], time() + 30, '/');
            $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
            if (isset($post['isAPIData']) && $post['isAPIData'] == 1) {
                $isAPIResponse = 1;
            } else {
                if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage($message['success']);
                    return $this->redirect()->refresh();
                }
            }
```

code for updating

```
            // success
            $text = $this->translate('The group %s has been updated successfully.');
            $message['success'] = sprintf($text, $group['name']);
            if (isset($post['isAPIData']) && $post['isAPIData'] == 1) {
                $isAPIResponse = 1;
                return [
                    'message'  => $message,
                    'isAPIResponse' => $isAPIResponse
                ];
            } else {
                if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage($message['success']);
                    $this->redirect()->refresh();
                }
            }
```

when `var_dump($message['success'])` the output is correct [image: var_dump($message['success']) output]

how to fix this?

Comment: _"replaces the message spaces with the + symbol"_ - but not all of them, if you look closely, but apparently only those in `$group['name']`. So that begs the question, where does that value come from.

Comment: @CBroe if I `var_dump($group['name'])` it is also a string output. the same `$group['name']` is used in the update message also and it works fine.

Comment: The laminas view helper flash messenger class uses an escaper instance. Are you sure your `$group['name']` value does not contain any hidden special chars?

Comment: @Marcel yeah I'm sure it doesn't have any hidden special chars. The problem is, on the update, it works fine but not when creating.

Comment: also, I have missed that, after the `else` block in create it redirect to the update page of the created group 
`return $this->redirect()->toRoute('group/update', ['group_id' => $group['group_id']]);`
it is only refresh when after updating
` $this->redirect()->refresh();`